# Why the switch between 'questions' and 'unanswered'?

Tags: bug

On all other stackexchange sites, in the main navigation links, 'questions' are the current questions, and 'unanswered' denotes the ones that haven't garnered any response in a while.  Why did this site switch them (and fairly recently at that)?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. What links are you following exactly? What URLs do the links bring you to? Please post screenshots and a precise description of where you're clicking. What browser are you using? Any browser extensions? Can you reproduce it in a private/incognito window?

Comment: Note that the main page (not the “Questions” or “Unanswered” links from the left side bar or top-left menu) remembers which tab you last looked at, between “Newest”, “Featured”, “Frequent”, “Votes”, “Active” and “Unanswered”.

Comment: Why?  When I click on a link I expect to go to a specific location, not whatever some idiot process thinks I should go to instead

Comment: So which link are you clicking? The _only_ link whose destination changes is the main page.